# How to set this button to center of x-axis using css?

Tags: html, css

I tried to set this button to center of x-axis using css but it does not work.

How can i do that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/9e9rb6L5/

this is html code.

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">start now</div>    
</div>
```

and this is css.

```
.one{
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.two{
    float: left;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You can't position an element that is floated. Remove the `float:left` from the button.

Comment: when remove float left from button, my button still long width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
You need to add `width: fit-content;` in .one class.

```css
.one{
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 36px;
    display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
       width: fit-content;
  text-align:center;
}
.two{
    float: left;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">start now</div>    
</div>
```

2. One more way: `display:table` in .one class

```css
.one{
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 36px;
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
  
}
.two{
    float: left;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">start now</div>    
</div>
```

3. 3rd way you can use `flex` property.

```css
.one{
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
.two{
    float: left;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">start now</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: For IE you can go with 3rd solution I added now, using flex. You can see the flex support here:https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto;`
requires a width

https://jsfiddle.net/9e9rb6L5/1/

Answer (score 1):

This solution to center a dom:

```
1. set the wrapper `text-align:center;` 
2. and then set the dom `margin:0 auto;` 
3. At last need to set the width of the dom.
```

In your code you should set the width of the `.one` and the `float:left;` in `.two` effect the style, just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/qoh1qLd7/

add `width:25%` and `margin:auto` in class one

```
    .one{
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    width:25%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

remove `float:left` from class two

```
.two{  
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

this should do the work

Answer (score 1):

Specify a width and remove the float: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ka1h5a6k/

```
.one{
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}
.two{
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To **centre the div**: Remove the float.
2. To make the **width automatically fit the size of the text**: display:inline-block;

No need to change anything in `.one`!

Run the snippet to see it in action.

```css
.one{
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.two{
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">start now</div>    
</div>

<p>Width changes automatically:, e.g. </p>

<div class="one">
    <div class="two">Another div with longer text</div>    
</div>
```

**Float** takes elements out of the flow of the page, so they can't be positioned.  Don't use float unless you actually want it to float!

Answer (score 1):

**remove float: left in your code**

```css
.one{
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.two{
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">start now</div>    
</div>
```